# After executing a period, Jupyter always display "kernel Restarting" accidently

Tags: jupyter

I am executing a code in sever with Docker and jupyter.
I set my container with a feature: restart=always.
But, the jupyter always show a same error: Kernel Restarting, The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

The code is based on Keras with TensorFlow.

In this way, I need to restart manually it. And I need to execute the code from beginning if I have no save the parameters. And I cann't find the error in time, so it is wasting time.

So, is there any way to set it automatically connect successfully.

[image]

Comment: whether I explain my question clearly?